# Trouble retrieving JSON format array from SQL (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, laravel

I'm here asking for help.

I've been thinking about storing JSON arrays into a columns of MySQL and retrieving their data.

The thing is that I don't know how to do it yet.

I've designed a table called employees, with these fields:

**id**: primary identifier
**json**: where the json array is being saved

It looks something like this:

[image]

What I need is to loop (iterate) through the array in the **json** field. I think I made it to get the data, with this code:

```
public function testjson() {

    $arr = DB::table('employees')
    ->where('json->name', 'John')
    ->get();


    return view('desktop.templates.testing', [
        'data' => json_decode($arr, true),
    ]);
}
```

By the time of looping into the view, I cannot access to that array, for as much as I tried.

I don't know how to loop through the json array into the view, for example, get the name of the employee and print it. I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

Can somebody help me? Is there a better way for accomplishing that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Laravel Model for this kind on stuff.

For example making model php for User.php

and adding the following code in model

```
    protected $casts = [
    'json' => 'array',
];
```

It will automatically do all the things under the box.

```
 $data = User::where('json->name', 'Muhammad')->first();

 foreach ($data->json as $key => $value) {
     echo $value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys So I finally found the solution of what I was trying to achieve.

The Controller looks like this:

```
$x = collect(json_decode(Test::all(), true)); // Test:all() gets all values from the table I was working on
return view('desktop.templates.testing', [
    'data' => $x
]);
```

In the view, now I can iterate easily:

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
    <h1>{{ $item['json']['name']}}</h1>
    <h2>Age: {{ $item['json']['age']}}</h2>
    <h2>City: {{ $item['json']['city'] }}</h2>
@endforeach
```

The final result:

[image]

Thank you everyone for your efforts. Hope this helps more people like me in the future :D